# How does Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio import data using a driver that doesn't exist on my computer?

Tags: python, sql-server, ms-access

**Context**

I have an MS Access database stored as a .mdb file.  I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to import the entire database to an existing SQL database.  My steps are:

1. Right click the database name, select Tools, select Import Data
2. Choose the Microsoft Jet driver and select the .mdb file
3. Choose the destination database and name the schema

The summary text block looked like this when I ran it, with the exception that I actually ran it instead of saved the process to file (sensitive information removed):

```
Click Finish to perform the following actions: 


Source Location : C:\Users\myname\directorypaths\accessdatabasefilename.mdb
Source Provider : Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
Destination Location : servername
Destination Provider : SQLNCLI11

Copy rows from `Table1` to [SchemaName].[Table1]
The new target table will be created.
Copy rows from `Table2` to [SchemaName].[Table2]
The new target table will be created.
Copy rows from `Table3` to [SchemaName].[Table3]
The new target table will be created.
Copy rows from `Table4` to [SchemaName].[Table4]
The new target table will be created.

The package will be saved to the package file "C:\Users\myname\Documents\myfilename.dtsx". 
The package will not be run immediately. 

Provider mapping file : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\MappingFiles\JetToMSSql9.xml
```

I want to pull the data from the .mdb file into Python for data manipulation instead of going through SQL server.  However, pyodbc lists only the following drivers:

```
['SQL Server',
 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']
```

**Question**

Why does SSMS list a driver that isn't on my computer?  How does SSMS get the .mdb data onto its SQL database without using that driver?  Can I leverage this to get the .mdb data into Python?

Comment: If your question is how to access a MS Access database from Python, I highly recommend you ask just that. Asking how SQL Server does it is confusion, and attracting the wrong experts.

Comment: I found many threads on the topic of accessing MS Access through Python, and all of them involve a driver that I don't have, nor am allowed to install (company IT rules).  I ask about SQL Server because it occurs to me that if SQL Server can do it without the right driver, then maybe I can convince Python to do it without the right driver.  Also, I figure the answer will be very educational either way.

Comment: SQL Server **does** have the right driver... but its not a Python driver.

Comment: _Why does SSMS list a driver that isn't on my computer_ Do you mean the Microsoft Jet driver?

Comment: Yes, the Microsoft Jet driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That driver (or really, OLEDB provider) is 32-bits. These JET providers/drivers only have 32-bits versions. If you use 64-bits Python, you can't use it. However, if you use 32-bits Python, you can use it just fine.

To answer your questions:

- Why does SSMS list a driver that isn't on my computer?

It doesn't. That provider is present on all modern Windows installations by default, and the associated ODBC driver as well.

- How does SSMS get the .mdb data onto its SQL database without using that driver?

It likely doesn't, but just uses that OLEDB provider.

- Can I leverage this to get the .mdb data into Python?

Yes, as long as you make sure to only use 32-bits Python.